# AngularJS and Apiary.IO - can't read any response headers?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, angularjs, apiary.io

I mocking my API using Apiary.io. But somehow I cannot read any headers from response object using angularJS. And I am sure i have at least Content-Type: application/json correctly set-up by checking in firebug. Code in Angular should read headers correctly too as i can print them when sending request to somewhere else than apiary.io...

```
  $http.get('http://ies.apiary.io/some').then(function(response) {  
    console.log("ok",response.headers('Content-Type'));
    },function(response){console.log("err",response);});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zMO0pXGsIdJkV0fZdBdw

Comment: Can you set up a Plunker or jsFiddle with the code so you can show us in context where it doesn't work? We can answer you much quicker that way.

Comment: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zMO0pXGsIdJkV0fZdBdw)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all boils down to a bug in firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=608735

For CORS request, firefox is not returning anything for req.getAllRequestHeaders(), although req.getRequestHeader('Content-Type') returns properly.

Either FF bug has to be fixed or Angular must work around it (as jQuery does) or you must go deeper and use XmlHttpRequest instance directly.

---

This was maybe also related, but probably not the core issue:

---

However, few days ago, Apiary.io was not setting `Max-Age` in `CORS` headers. Thus, if you had a minimal blueprint, you might have `CORS` pre-flight response cached and thus subsequent requests may be disallowed even if you added additional resources to your blueprint.

`Max-Age` is now set to 10 seconds, so it should work properly. However, depending on your browser, pre-flight cache might still affect you. Try purging it or test this app in another browser.

Comment: works fine in Chrome, however Firefox still **NOT**. Firefox was purged by clearing Cached Web Content and clearing Offline Web Content and User Data. Even private browsing mode did not help..

Comment: @JakubKuchar It works for me in FF too. Could you please paste your request/response pair (or screenshot) on the OPTIONS request somewhere? Or perhaps, please create ticket through "contact support" on http://support.apiary.io/ as this looks more like apiary debugging than Angular-related issue.

Comment: i've created 2 screenshots with [Firefox](http://www.bounceapp.com/posts/new?screen_id=312065) and with [Chrominium](http://www.bounceapp.com/posts/new?screen_id=312066) using bounceapp.com hope they will be available as this was my first time using bounceapp.com

Comment: ticket on support.apiary.io was created

Comment: AngularJS issue is 3 months old https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1468

Comment: @Almad, any idea how to get the actual XHR object from within an interceptor?

Comment: @deitch It should be displayed in Apiary's inspector. If not, please let us know at support@apiary.io