# Reading response headers when using $http of Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using `$http` to make an api call which is sending some custom header like `X-Foo`. However I can't yet figure out how to read them. Inside the `$http({...}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {...})` function, `headers` is a function that should give me a hash of all headers but it only shows the header `content-type`. Is there a way to get the response headers ?

Comment: Are you using Firefox? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188662/angularjs-and-apiary-io-cant-read-any-response-headers.

Comment: No, chrome. Does the FF specific fix work for chrome ?

Comment: Are the requests being made to a different domain or the same domain? I tested sending the request to the same domain and I am able to see the custom headers.

Comment: You are right, the issue was due to different domains. I could finally get the custom headers to show after I made the server to send the header Access-Control-Expose-Headers.

Comment: Great!!! I'm glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @JoyDutta You should create an answer, so to make this question not listed under "unanswered" tab.

Comment: @JoyDutta, it's still under the unanswered tab, you should create an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The custom headers will be visible in same domain. However, for the crossdomain situation, the server has to send `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Foo, ...` header to make the custom headers visible.

Comment: It appears that you must specify the actual header name instead of a wildcard. `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:*` does not work, but `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Etag` does.

Comment: this did not seem to work for me with angular's `$http`

Comment: Seems that even standard headers don't work with CORS without this workaround. Had to add this: Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition to make the content-disposition header visible in angularjs.

Comment: This is how to do it on a rails backend: http://jaketrent.com/post/expose-http-headers-in-cors/

Comment: You should let angular handle the cookies. You'll need to do this on the servlet side to allow the other domain to set cookies: ` resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");`

Answer (score 0):

Spring 4.0+ provide @CrossOrigin annotation which has following parameters

1. origins = list of Comma separated origin.
2. exposedHeaders =  list ofcomma separated count custom parameters.

**example**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", exposedHeaders ="X-Total-Count")
```