# AngularJS $http response header

Tags: angularjs, response-headers

This simple problem is bugging me. I have a custom value in my response header from the Web Api Rest server.
I can see it it Firebug as:
X-TotalPages 204
I try to get it in my AngularJS controller. Code below.
But I cant find any good examples how to do this. 
 console.log(headers()['X-TotalPages']); logs 'undefined'

```
var assets = angular.module("Assets", ['ui.bootstrap']);
assets.controller('AssetSearchController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = 'very';
    $scope.getItems = function () {
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:57772/api/assets', params: { search: 1, page: 0, pageSize: 10 } }
            ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.currentPage = 4;                
                console.log(headers()['X-TotalPages']);

            $scope.items = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(status));
        });

    };
```

Comment: What's the output of  console.log(headers()); ?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038436/reading-response-headers-when-using-http-of-angularjs

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  console.log(headers()); returns Headers: [object Object] so its there. I have already looked at the other issue and it does not help. This is my response, it seems to be returned by the rest server :[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/5lrzft.png[/IMG]

Comment: And my web-config in Rest service:<httpProtocol> 
      <customHeaders>
        <add name ="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-TotalPages"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> 
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,DELETE,PATCH,PUT,OPTIONS" /> 
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" /> 
      </customHeaders> 
    </httpProtocol>

Comment: I think the header value is there as you can see in the image. I think its my lack of basic javascript knowledge thats the main problem. Maybe is just my syntax in retrieving the data from the headers object

Comment: Shouldn't it be headers('X-TotalPages')?

Comment: There you are!!! Thank you! Such a simple beautiful answer. Lack of basic knowledge from my side was the problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use: `headers('X-TotalPages')`

(Posting Wawy's answer so the question can be resolved.)

Answer (score 5):

For **$http(url).then()** syntax which replaced
**$http(url).success().error()** in newer versions of AngularJS, I used this:

```
$http(url).then(function(response){
            response.headers("X-TotalPages");
     });
```

Just using **response.headers()** will give all headers attached in response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use success callback of promise

```
promise.then(function(resp){
            resp.headers().token(variablename)

     });
```