# ng-token-auth not persisting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authentication, devise

I have a pretty bare-bones application at the moment using `ng-token-auth` and rails' `devise-token-auth`.  It is running fine and the $auth methods are working well (for example, logging in).  However, upon page refresh the `access-token` doesn't persist and doesn't get written to the cookie using ipCookie.

My rails app is forwarding the proper headers as seen below:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Access-Control-Max-Age:0
access-token:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
client:nYMXLxnuO7BIGZkdXkZ_Xg
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 09 May 2015 21:41:56 GMT
ETag:"c16291f5079691a2528d5a7876627ede"
expiry:1431294116
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.5.20
token-type:Bearer
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
uid:tester53@mailinator.com
Vary:Origin
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:2b224904-944c-48f7-aa4e-d0407e26e893
X-Runtime:0.230242
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

But when it gets run through the `updateHeadersFromResponse` method of `ng-token-auth` the headers are returning null-- specifically in lines 588 of ng-token-auth.js

```
updateHeadersFromResponse = function($auth, resp) {
  var key, newHeaders, val, _ref;
  newHeaders = {};
  _ref = $auth.getConfig().tokenFormat;
  for (key in _ref) {
    val = _ref[key];
    if (resp.headers(key)) {
      newHeaders[key] = resp.headers(key);
    }
  }
  if (tokenIsCurrent($auth, newHeaders)) {
    return $auth.setAuthHeaders(newHeaders);
  }
};
```

Has anyone encountered this?  Why would the header not be passed to this `$httpProvider` method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer in this post [Angular.js saying custom HTTP response header is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139176/angular-js-saying-custom-http-response-header-is-null)

I was using a multi-domain setup so the API domain needed to have some additional exposed headers in the CORS configuration.  So in the rails-cors gem I added an additional exposed value for the access-token:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins 'api.com'

    resource '*',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options, :head],
      :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
      :max_age => 0
  end
end
```

UPDATE: Exposed all fields required by angular, not just one ones that made it work.

Comment: Yes yes yes!! I've been searching the internet for days and this finally did it.

Comment: Two words: LIFE SAVER!

Comment: thanks a lot, saved me a lot of debugging and works like charm on reload!