# X-AUTH-TOKEN returns null even though it is present in header

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am using angular JS to login to my app. On the server, it returns a X-AUTH-TOKEN. When I do a JSON request. The header response looks like this...

```
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 12:44:05 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: chrome-extension://gmodihnfibbjdecbanmpmbmeffnmloel
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-AUTH-TOKEN: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJiaWxseWpvZSJ9.le0y_pOfQAyLJO4IJ4ZjQQqgqgiN2xtpLAzORawoDm4O4euHFh32LtjMrBUTkr8G2LeY_2bALe_rcm3LY_NlSg
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me
Content-Length: 88
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Expires: 0
```

As you can see. X-AUTH-TOKEN is present. But when I try to retrieve it and save it to local storage...

```
  $http.post(loginUrl)
  .success(function(data, status,headers) {
    $scope.hello = data;
    var TOKEN = headers("X-AUTH-TOKEN");
    window.localStorage['X-AUTH-TOKEN-TRIVIA'] = headers("X-AUTH-TOKEN");
  })
```

It always returns NULL. Why is it not retrieving the token if its clearly in the header ?

I have also used single quotes.

```
  $http.post(loginUrl)
  .success(function(data, status,headers) {
    $scope.hello = data;
    var TOKEN = headers('X-AUTH-TOKEN');
    window.localStorage['X-AUTH-TOKEN-TRIVIA'] = headers('X-AUTH-TOKEN');
  })
```

Comment: `headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN']` instead of `headers("X-AUTH-TOKEN")`. It is an array not a function afaik.

Comment: @M.Deinum is right. Also check your browser console log (F12), you'll see an error saying `TypeError: header is not a function`.

Comment: I've used both. I've updated my code. still NULL. And I have also saved in a variable to see if its there. still null.

Comment: And no errors in console

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... Thanks to another post

[Angular.js saying custom HTTP response header is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139176/angular-js-saying-custom-http-response-header-is-null)

The problem is server side. You must add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Auth-Token`

In my case using Spring Boot or Spring. You probably would have to add this in your CorsFilter

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Auth-Token");
```