# AngularJS - Cannot read response headers from $http

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, angular-http

My http response contains the headers Authentication (as mentioned here: `Authentication:76efbc0946773b62c93e952b502a47acd898200f6f80dc46ac87ffc501c00780`) when I inspect the request with the inspector, but a call to `headers("Authentication")` returns `null`

```
return $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(headers("Authentication"));
})
```

Do you have any idea about what I could be doing the wrong way ?

FYI, i've tried to switch it back to a "promise" way, with `.then`, and the issue is still the same.

Comment: You probably need to add Access-Control-Expose-Headers to your response from the server to make it accessible - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038436/reading-response-headers-when-using-http-of-angularjs?lq=1

Comment: @BradBarber that's it. Reply if you want to get the bounty.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your code looks good but if it's a CORS request the server needs to include Access-Control-Expose-Headers: {any custom headers} in the response.

There's a previous question/answer with more details: [Reading response headers when using $http of Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038436/reading-response-headers-when-using-http-of-angularjs?lq=1)

Comment: Will enabling CORS not impact on security. Shouldn't we send the required data in response body.

Answer (score 5):

In success callback put :

```
console.log(headers('content-type'));
console.log(headers());  // All headers
```

I think the first line return a result in your cas.
In the seconde, have you got the 'Authentication' ?

The custom headers will be visible in same domain. In crossdomain case, you need to send `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authentication, ...` header from server.