# Get own headers $Resource AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have a REST API in GO language and the front-end in Angularjs , but when I get my resource in angular my custom header don't exist.

Controller:

```
  Persons.query(
    function (data, headerGetter, status) {

      var headers = headerGetter();

      console.log(headers["X-Total-Count"]); //PRINT: undefined
      console.log(headers) //PRINT: {Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8}
      console.log(data); //PRINT: [{name:'mr x', age:'67'}, ....]

    },
    function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Model:

```
myApp.factory("Persons", function ($resource) {
  return $resource(api_url+"/persons");
});
```

Response Chrome or Firefox, any client:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:1839
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 12 Mar 2015 21:53:54 GMT
X-Total-Count:150
```

Comment: I have removed the Go tag because the header is clearly visible .. so Go has done its job. I have added the Angular tag for you .. because this is an Angular question.

Comment: Can you display the output of  `console.log(headers)` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I get my resource in angular, my custom header don't exist"? When do you test this? In which code?

Comment: The custom headers are not even returned by the internal call to `$http`.

Comment: This seems to be a CORS issue see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038436/reading-response-headers-when-using-http-of-angularjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making a request from a different domain than the one where your `API` is located, operation which is called `Cross-site HTTP requests ( CORS )`

In order to use custom headers you need to set another one called `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

> If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to
>   use the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. The value of this header
>   is a comma-delimited list of response headers you want to expose to
>   the client.
>
> This header lets a server whitelist headers that browsers are allowed
>   to access. For example:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-My-Custom-Header,X-Another-Custom-Header
```

> This allows the X-My-Custom-Header and
>   X-Another-Custom-Header headers to be exposed to the browser.

---

The way I do it in `.NET` ( I suppose it's kinda similar in `Go`):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Total-Pages, X-Records");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("X-Total-Pages", pages.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("X-Records", records.ToString());
```

And in `AngularJS` I'm getting headers like this :

```
var headers = headers();
headers['x-total-pages']
```

Answer (score 2):

So this IS a CORS issue. Setting

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:"X-Total-Count"
```

in the server response solves your problem.

You will need to parse the response to a number:

```
parseInt(headers('X-Total-Count'), 10)
```