# How can I get response header values with ngResource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I'm developping an application using javascript angularJS library at client side and spring framework (java) for back-end implementation.
For one of the services I return a parameter in Response Header. The issue is I cannot get this value after the service call.

This is the factory:

```
angular.module('app')
        .factory('financeDocumentService', ['$resource', 'SERVER_FOR_SERVICES',
            function ($resource, SERVER_FOR_SERVICES) {
                var url = SERVER_FOR_SERVICES + '/sapi/finance/document';
                return $resource(url + '/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
                    'get': {method: 'GET'},
                    'isReferencedDocumentIdCompensated':
                            {
                                method: 'GET',
                                isArray: false,
                                url: url + '/is_compensated?referenced_document_id=:id',
                                params: {id: '@id'},
                                headers: {'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'IsCompensated'},
                                transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
                                    response = {};
                                    response.data = data;
                                    response.headers = headers();
                                    console.log(headers());
                                    return response;
                                }
                            }
                });
            }]);
```

This is the code at controller:

```
                            $scope.flightRecords[i].financeDocument =
                                    financeDocumentService
                                    .isReferencedDocumentIdCompensated(
                                        {id: $scope.flightRecords[i].id}).$promise.then(
                                        function(data) {
                                            console.log(data.headers);

                                        }
                                        );
```

This is the result:

**Object { cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must…", pragma: "no-cache", expires: "0" }**

And this is the header list values:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8383
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 29 Jun 2017 18:19:23 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
X-Application-Context: application:local
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
access-control-allow-credentials: true
isCompensated: false
x-content-type-options: nosniff
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021198/get-own-headers-resource-angularjs

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shantanu!! now it works!!