# Access-Control-Expose-Headers Configuration for Custom Response Headers AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, cors

I'm implementing custom response headers on a resource, after [reading over a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038436/reading-response-headers-when-using-http-of-angularjs), I added an 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' to my CORS headers, but I must not have something configured correctly.

Here are the headers I receive on a GET request of the resource: I receive a 'Response-Header' of "Steve", which should be allowed by the 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers'

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, Request-Header, Response-Header
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Response-Header
Response-Header:Steve
```

But, Angular is still does not have access to that custom header. I get back my custom Request-Header, but not my custom Response-Header:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "content": "Hello, frank!"
  },
  "status": 200,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "url": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/greeting",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application\/json, text\/plain, *\/*",
      "Request-Header": "frank"
    }
  },
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

Angular 1.3 $httpProvider.interceptor:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('headerDemoUiApp')
  .factory('AuthInterceptor', function AuthInterceptor(nameService) {

    return {
      request: handleRequest,
      response: handleResponse
    };

    function handleRequest(config) {
      if (angular.isDefined(config.headers)) {
        config.headers['Request-Header'] = "frank";
      }
      return config;
    }

    function handleResponse(response) {
      console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));

      if (angular.isDefined(response.config.headers['Response-Header'])) {
        var respHead = response.config.headers['Response-Header'];
        console.log('Response-Header: ' + respHead);
        nameService.responsename=respHead;
      }
      return response;
    }

  });
```

And, the Spring version 4.1.6 @RestController adding the header.

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(
            @RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestHeader("Request-Header") String headerName) {

        // Sets our custom response header
        response.setHeader("Response-Header","Steve");

        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(template, headerName));
    }
}
```

[API Code Repo](https://github.com/AndrewBell/HeaderDemoApi)

[UI Code Repo](https://github.com/AndrewBell/HeaderDemoUi)

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is with your API `GreetingController.java`

change the greeting method to return ResponseEntity and use HttpHeaders, as below

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name, @RequestHeader("Request-Header") String headerName) {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
        // Sets our custom response header
        headers.add("Response-Header","Steve");
        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),String.format(template, headerName)), headers, HttpStatus.OK); 
    }
```

Below was my headers response with Postman client

```
Content-Length → 2
Content-Type → text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date → Wed, 27 May 2015 15:53:47 GMT
Response-Header → Steve
Server → Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: That seems to be the ticket! There's no way for Spring to send back a header, if you're only sending back a payload, instead of an entire ResponseEntity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set which custom headers will be exposed on response headers, on a list. Like:

```
 List<String> customHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    customHeaders.add("<Custom header name>");
    headers.setAccessControlExposeHeaders(customHeaders);
```