# How to read Token from header of a response in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, token

I am implementing authentication where I added a token in response from server side.
[image]

I am trying to read this header value returned from server in angularjs however I don't see this header value present. Here is my javascript console.
[image]

**EDIT:**

```
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                var response = task.Result;
                if (response.RequestMessage.Headers.Contains(TOKEN_NAME))
                {
                    string token = response.RequestMessage.Headers.GetValues(TOKEN_NAME).FirstOrDefault();
                    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", TOKEN_NAME);
                    response.Headers.Add(TOKEN_NAME, token);
                }

                return response;
            });
```

Comment: Possible answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038436/reading-response-headers-when-using-http-of-angularjs?rq=1)

Comment: @Dvir: You comment added equally to reach out to working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the access/authenticate endpoint returning the token as data in the success method or is the token being set in the server side code?

-Update-

If you set the token in `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader('X-Token', "<some token value">);` You should be able to grab it in your $http promise

```
$http.get("<api endpoint>").then(function(data){
            $log.log("data.config", data.config);
            $log.log("data.headers()", data.headers());
            $log.log("X-Token Header", data.headers()['x-token']);
});
```

data.config is the headers sent to the server such as the accept and any authorization headers.

**`data.headers()`** is the function that returns all headers that were set server side.
`response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", TOKEN_NAME);` this line will ensure this header is available to the server

[image]

[image]

[image: data.config vs data.headers()]

So if I understand correctly your passing x-token in the header of the api request and the Delegating Handler is looking for TOKEN_NAME and then resetting it and then your trying to access it in the promise of $http. I just put together a test for this case and im getting back x-token;

-Sample angular app

```
        (function () {
        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["x-token"] = "";
        });


        app.controller('home', function ($http, $log) {
            $http.get('/api/car/get')
                .then(function (response) {
                $log.log("Response headers",response.headers());
                $log.log(response.headers()["x-token"]);
            });
        });

    })();
```

-Console window
[image]

-CustomDelegatingHandler i dont use the variable token because I dont have a token endpoint to get one. Instead I just passed back a random GUID.

```
 protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
          CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                var response = task.Result;
                //Are you sure your passing this check by setting the x-token common header in your angular $http requests?
                if (response.RequestMessage.Headers.Contains(TOKEN_NAME))
                {
                    string token = response.RequestMessage.Headers.GetValues(TOKEN_NAME).FirstOrDefault();
                    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", TOKEN_NAME);
                    response.Headers.Add(TOKEN_NAME, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                }

                return response;
            }, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: Token is being returned in header and not data. I am not sure if sending token as data would be a good practice. Currently I am setting token in header on server side code.

Comment: I am not getting HttpContext into my DelegatingHandler class

Comment: how are you setting the header then?

Comment: Just highlighting your key take away from your answer to reflect what I was missing. Thanks for your help. It worked when I used data.headers(). This is not available in `$http.success(data, status)`

Comment: You can try it in the success method it would be $http.get (endpoint).success (function(response, staus, headers){ $log.log (headers ('x-token');});  I'm not 100% on this being correct as I have never actually tried it.