# In an Angular http response interceptor, how can I get at the actual xhr object?

Tags: angularjs

The method for a response interceptor is:

```
return {
  response: function(response) {
    // processing here
  }
};
```

Because of the issues with CORS response headers and various bugs, I want to access the xhr object directly and retrieve specific headers. However, `response` seems to only have:

`data` - the returned body
`config` - the original request
`status` - the response status
`headers()` - the problematic function that gets stuck on the bugs

How can I get at the actual `xhr` object so I can look at the headers directly?

For reference: [AngularJS and Apiary.IO - can't read any response headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188662/angularjs-and-apiary-io-cant-read-any-response-headers)

I want to do option 3, and work with xhr directly, but how do I get to it in an interceptor?

Comment: To clarify, something like `response.headers()['access-control-allow-origin']` isn't giving you the data you're looking for?

Comment: It is, but only in certain browser revisions. Many still have bugs that still prevent it from working. I want to go straight at the xhr object to bypass the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to access the `xhr` object directly exposed to interceptors. However, If this is all due to the Firefox bug mentioned, you can do the following to get access to the headers you're looking for in FF:

Patch 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.2/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L76

Add the headers you need. Currently it's only asking for the specified headers in that array for the FF work-around. You'd add something like:

```
simpleHeaders = ["Cache-Control", "Content-Language", "Content-Type",
                              "Expires", "Last-Modified", "Pragma", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"];
```